# update the column specifed in the text box from the server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I want to update a column of a table where the column name will be entered in the textbox while executing. The following code is not performing any action. TextBox14 contains the column name and TextBox12 consists the value to be updated.

```
        Dim squery As String = "SELECT name,days from definedLeave"
                        Dim cmd6 As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(squery, con)
                        Dim dr6 As SqlDataReader = cmd6.ExecuteReader()
                        Dim i As Integer = 0
                        While dr6.Read()
                            Try
                                s = dr6(i).ToString
                                TextBox14.Text = s
                                a = dr6(i + 1).ToString
                                TextBox12.Text = a
                               Dim sql = "update empLeave set " & TextBox14.Text.Trim & "=@na where epid='" + txtCode.Text + "'"

                                Using com7 = New SqlCommand(sql, con)
                                    com7.Parameters.AddWithValue("@na", TextBox12.Text)
                                    com7.ExecuteNonQuery()
                                End Using
                            Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("HELLO")
    End Try
                        End While
                        com7.Dispose()
                        dr6.Close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, parameters can only be used for values, not identifiers.  They're just like variables in VB - you can't use the contents of one variable to stand for another variable in VB either.

The silly thing is that you're trying to use a parameter where you can't and then where you can, for the `epid` value, you use string concatenation.  Your code should look something like this:

```
Dim sql = "UPDATE empleave SET [" & TextBox14.Text & "] = @na WHERE epid = @epid"

Using com7 = New SqlCommand(sql, con)
    com7.Parameters.AddWithValue("@na", TextBox12.Text)
    com7.Parameters.AddWithValue("@epid", txtCode.Text)

    com7.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

That still leaves you open to SQL injection though, so you should make absolutely sure that you validate the column name first.  In fact, what you should do is query the database to get the column names first and then put them in a `ComboBox`.  That way you are guaranteed that the user will select a valid value.

Comment: @jimcilhinney both the format doesnt work. Actually I have taken content from another table as column names for this table.I have edited the code part with the full code. please check

Comment: Perhaps you could be a bit more specific than "doesn't work".  It's no fun for us to guess what actually happens when you already know.  Error messages are not provided for fun; they are for information.

Comment: If no exception is thrown then the call is succeeding so either there are no matching rows to update or the matching rows are updated. There's no other possible outcome.  What value does `ExecuteNonQuery` return?  If it's zero then there are no matching records and if it's not zero then that many records matched and were updated.

Comment: ExcecuteNonQuery does not execute only. Once it reaches update statement catch statement is executed.

Comment: Good grief! You said earlier that there was no error and now you're saying that a catch statement is executed. Catcxh statements are executed when an error occurs, i.e. they catch the exception that was thrown. That exception has a `Message` property that tells you what went wrong. If you want us to help you fix what went wrong then providing that information would be a good idea, especially when we ask for it specifically.

Comment: The one thing that comes to mind that might cause an issue in this case is a column name that is a reserved word or contains spcial characters, e.g. spaces.  Such names should be avoided in the first place so such issues should never arise but, just in case, you can escape the column name by wrapping it in brackets.  I have updated my code example accordingly.

Comment: update empLeave set [dl]='2' where epid='3567' While executing the query string in sql will be the above one. I think its proper. But could not identify where it is going wrong

Comment: Problem arises in com7.ExecuteNonQuery() part. Everything works good till control reaches that statement.

Comment: We already know that `ExecuteNonQuery` is the issue.  It throws an exception and that exception contains an error message.  Give us that error message or just go away because you're wasting our time otherwise.

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.

Comment: Finally! Why was that so hard? Now that you have provided the error message I can look back at your code and the issue is obvious. You're calling `ExecuteReader` and then calling `ExecuteNonQuery` while the data reader is still open. By default, a `SqlConnection` only allows one command to be executed at a time. You have basically three option: 1) use a data adapter to populate a `DataTable` and loop through that so there's no open data reader; 2) use a different `SqlConnection` for the second command; 3) enable MARS in your connection string so one connection supports multiple commands.

Comment: MARS is Multiple Active Result Sets: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-AU?query=mars&emptyWatermark=true&ac=2

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
Dim sql as string= "update empLeave set " & TextBox14.Text.Trim & "=@na where 
epid='" + txtCode.Text + "'"

  Using com7 = New SqlCommand(sql, con)
      com7.Parameters.AddWithValue("@na", TextBox12.Text)
      com7.ExecuteNonQuery()
  End Using
```

Comment: I tried the above code but it dint work. Table is not getting updated and dosent get any error message.

Comment: did you check your query. Post your query

Comment: Dim sql = "update empLeave set " & TextBox14.Text.Trim & "=@na where epid='" + txtCode.Text + "'"
Using com7 = New SqlCommand(sql, con)
com7.Parameters.AddWithValue("@na", TextBox12.Text)
com7.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using

Comment: put break point in dim sql in check what string return assign in sql

Comment: "NOTHING" is assigned

Comment: the control goes to exception part

Comment: Problem arises in com7.ExecuteNonQuery() part. Everything works good till control reaches that statement.

Comment: post the query (which string passed in sql)

Comment: I am getting exception "System.InvalidOperationException: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first."

Comment: why are you give [ and ] for column name

Comment: Run the update query directly in back end. It execute or throw error ah?

Comment: Ok, then the error not in query check the other lines

Comment: I used MARS and now the code is working properly. Thank you for helping me :)